# How to handle undefined object property in angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I tried to fix the undefined error by setting the object property value to an empty string but its still giving the error as mentioned below:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'notes' of undefined

**TS**

```
let notes;
if (typeof manufacturer_field.manufacturer_guidelines[0].notes == undefined){
  notes = '';
} else {
  notes = manufacturer_field.manufacturer_guidelines[0].notes;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<p *ngIf="field.notes?.length">{{field.notes}}</p>
```

I referred this answer but that didn't work: [How to handle 'undefined' in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984721/how-to-handle-undefined-in-javascript)

Comment: The problem isn't about `notes`. It's about `field` and/or `manufacturer_field.manufacturer_guidelines[0]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If notes array element 0 is undefined, then this will throw an error:

```
if (typeof manufacturer_field.manufacturer_guidelines[0].notes == undefined){
```

because you are checking if the property is undefined, when what is actually undefined is the .manufacturer_guidelines[0] item.

instead, you can do:

```
if (!manufacturer_field.manufacturer_guidelines[0]){
     manufacturer_field.manufacturer_guidelines[0] = (assign it whatever value belong to this sort of item, and then once you know it is valid, then add notes)
}
```

Also, you are assigning the string to "notes" variable, not the actual array item.

So lets say i had a cars array:

```
if (!cars[0]) {
   cars[0] = <Car>{};
   cars[0].color = "blue";
}
```